# Polylang is changing my homepage - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, polylang

I just finished my first custom wordpress site, using my custom theme, and now, I was starting to translate the site, I need it to have 3 languages.

So, I installed the plugin [Polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/). But, I don't know why, when this plugin is active, my home page that is a custom page (page-home.php) is not being considered the homepage anymore. Since I never used this plugin before and I don't have much knowledge in wordpress, I have no idea how to solve this problem. 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: So if you go to Home or whatever the page is called in the backend, do you have the template set to whatever you call it in the template? Also, did you go to settings->general and make sure your homepage displays that static page?

Comment: Yes, my custom page page-home.php was set as the home page on settings->general. If I disable the plugin, everything works well. Do I have to set any specific configuration on Polylang?

Comment: Sorry, I really don't know anything about the plugin, I was just covering some basics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem. If you are using a custom page as your homepage, you first have to edit it. Just go there and save it, to assign this page to the default language you chose.

After that, you have to go to every page, post, custom post, and taxonomy, and save it using the default language. If you don't do that, the posts or the other contents of that current language will not be shown on the site, cause they have no language associated to it.

Then, you have to create a new version of every content you have on the admin (posts, pages, taxonomies) for the other languages you gonna use.